# How to pass input from user into an INSERT query (MySQL) ? GO

Tags: mysql, go, user-input

beginner coder here. I would like to know how to take the user input (scanner) and create a new row in a MySQL database. Below is the code I use to insert without asking for the user input.

```
func insert(tabel string) {

    login := dbGebruikersnaam + ":" + dbWachtwoord   
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", login+"@/vanderbinckesdb")

    insert, err := db.Exec("INSERT INTO bakfiets VALUES ( 8, 'TEST', 'TEST', 10, 10, 10 )")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(insert)
}
```

I would like to ask the user to input the values themselves with (scanner) if that is possible. I have made the following struct for it.

```
package main

type Bakfiets struct {   
    Bakfietsnummer        int   
    Naam                string  
    Type            string  
    Huurprijs       float64  
    Aantal          int  
    Aantal_verhuurd int  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass params to `db.Exec`. `$1, $2, $3...` are placeholders for them which also ensure protection against SQL injection. Something like this:

```
func insert(b *Bakfiets) error {

    login := dbGebruikersnaam + ":" + dbWachtwoord   
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", login+"@/vanderbinckesdb")

    insert, err := db.Exec("INSERT INTO bakfiets VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)", b.Bakfietsnummer, b.Naam, b.Type, b.Huurprijs, b.Aantal, b.Aantal_verhuurd)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println(insert)
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thank you for The asnwer. How do I combine that with the fmt.Scan() function?